# Connect a vibration motor to a headphone jack

Tags: amplifier, rectifier, vibration, vibration-motor

I would like to solve the following problem:

I have a a variometer-device for an RC plane. Its receiver has a standard 3.5 mm headphone jack that provides a beeping sounds to my headphones. I would like to replace the headphones by a "device" with a little vibration motor (just like those built into modern phones) so that I can feel if my plane climbs or sinks instead of hear it.

Now I assume that the receiver delivers an A/C signal to the headphones at a relatively low current, but I couldn't find any data about that on the internet. The vibration motor needs D/C and takes a current of about 200 mA.

Can anyone provide data what maximum voltage such a "standard" audio jack provides? What would I need to connect the vibration motor to it? Will I most likely need an extra battery for the motor and thus amplify and rectify the signal? What would be my best bet?

Comment: How clean is the signal?  Is there noise?  Does the tone vary?  If it's fairly clean you could probably use an op-amp to create a bandpass filter and level detector, and drive the motor with a simple NPN transistor.  But circuit complexity may be used by sampling the signal with a microcontroller ADC and doing the decisioning in software.  Most chipsets used for R/C on 2.4 GHz are bidirectional, meaning there is a latent capability for digital telemetry which would be even simpler.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score -1):

To start with you really need an oscilloscope to look at the range of signal that comes out of the receiver and goes to the head phones. Can you see bursts of signal that correspond to the "beeps" with little or no signal in between?

Secondly you need to conceptually decide how the beeping sounds will be "felt". We have no idea here of the duration of each beep nor what rate the beeps occur. It is highly likely that there cannot be direct conversion of a single beep to a powered on pulse to the vibrator motor. The motor likely has a response time that is more typical for the ring duration of phone which is in the seconds range.

Unless you understand the parameters here it is not time to start building anything. The beep characteristics and the motor response time will fully dictate the type of circuit design that would be required to achieve the vague goal that you have expressed.

Comment: One can probably accomplish the characterization with an everyday soundcard (and possibly a passive attenuator/DC blocking capacitor) instead of a more expensive oscilloscope.

Comment: `The motor likely has a response time that is more typical for the ring duration of phone which is in the seconds range` Pager/Cell motors don't need seconds...

Comment: @Passerby - If you were the one to down vote this answer please have the hudspa to say so. Contrary to what you wrote the ring cadences of ring on and off do have envelop times in the seconds range.

Comment: Hows this for hudspa ***I WAS THE ONE THAT DOWN VOTED IF IT WASNT OBVIOUS***